# javascript/google maps: convert location object to string

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to find out how to convert the following object from using the google location api into a string

```
initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

The above pulls your location.  However, I can't figure out a way to see what it is as a string so that I can work with it.  When I alert it, I get undefined and I've tried usual suspect properties and they don't display. I need to find out what it is so I can feed it into the directions service which takes "Boston" or lat lon or similar string an input.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please refer the below link.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y829C/1/

```
Here you can enter zip code and get the latitude and longitude.

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addresscity }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                  zoom: 8,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  };
```